# Open last session (State) in new browser tab

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

When I am typing the URL again it's going to login page instead of going to the last session or page.
I am using angular 6 routing.

Comment: Please give us some more details about your code.

Comment: Give more info about what you want to accomplish! Answer: You can use local storage to store your last location.

Comment: hi, Welcome to SO. Please [Read How to ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)